# Подсчитать произведение элементов массива, которые стоят на нечетных местах

Tags: c++

Реализую функции, которые подсчитывают произведение элементов массива, стоящих на нечетных местах.
Сумма работает. Произведение - нет. Что не так? Постоянно выводится 0.
В результат положил 1...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// массивы чисел
double Arr_double[5] = {1.2, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
float Arr_float[5] = {6.1, 7.1, 8.1, 9.1, 10.1};
long Arr_long[5] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

// прототипы перегруженных функций
double product(double * Arr);
float product(float * Arr);
long product(long * Arr);

int main() {
  cout << product(Arr_double);
  
  return 0;
}

// реализация прототипов
double product(double * Arr) {
    double result = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Arr); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            result *= Arr[i]; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите:

```
double product(double * Arr) {
    double result = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Arr); i++) {
```

Что такое у вас `Arr` в функции? Указатель. Значит, `sizeof(Arr)` - количество байт, занимаемое указателем. 4 в 32-разрядной системе, 8 - в 64-разрядной.

Вероятно, у вас 65-разрядная программа, вы выходите за пределы переданного массива и попадаете на ноль или иную неприятность - в любом случае UB...

Comment: Понял, буду передавать размер массива параметром